# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

Tags: java

I am getting the error as mentioned below, while running the feed utility. I am trying to load an image "**logo.png**". The `slf4j` jar file is also available in the runtime classpath. But still I am getting this error.

```
Oct 16, 2012 7:34:11 PM com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataload.FeedRetriever  invokeDataLoad
SEVERE: An error occurred while performing data load.
Throwable occurred: com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataload.exception.DataLoadException: 
An error occurred while executing the data load. 

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

    at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataload.DataLoaderMain.execute(DataLoaderMain.java:664)
    at com.ibm.commerce.content.commands.DataLoadInvoker.execute(DataLoadInvoker.java:101)
    at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataload.FeedRetriever.invokeDataLoad(FeedRetriever.java:244)
    at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataload.FeedRetriever.execute(FeedRetriever.java:172)
    at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataload.FeedRetriever.main(FeedRetriever.java:321)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataload.DataLoaderMain.execute(DataLoaderMain.java:488)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at org.apache.wink.client.ClientConfig.<clinit>(ClientConfig.java:52)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:167)
    at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataload.feedreader.AtomReader.getFeed(AtomReader.java:104)
    at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataload.feedreader.AtomReader.getEntries(AtomReader.java:147)
    at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataload.feedreader.AtomReader.getEntries(AtomReader.java:1)
    at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataload.feedreader.BaseFeedReader.init(BaseFeedReader.java:252)
    at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataload.AbstractBusinessObjectLoader.initializeDataReaders(AbstractBusinessObjectLoader.java:1344)
    at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataload.AbstractBusinessObjectLoader.init(AbstractBusinessObjectLoader.java:369)
    at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataload.BusinessObjectLoader.init(BusinessObjectLoader.java:65)
    at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataload.DataLoaderMain.execute(DataLoaderMain.java:431)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.lang.ClassNotFoundException.<init>(ClassNotFoundException.java:76)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:396)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:660)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:358)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:626)
    ... 16 more
Oct 16, 2012 7:34:11 PM com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataload.FeedRetriever main
SEVERE: An error occurred while performing data load.
Throwable occurred: com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataload.exception.DataLoadException: An error has occurred.  If this problem persists, contact product support.
    at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataload.FeedRetriever.invokeDataLoad(FeedRetriever.java:247)
    at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataload.FeedRetriever.execute(FeedRetriever.java:172)
    at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataload.FeedRetriever.main(FeedRetriever.java:321)
```

Comment: Was sl4j jar in  library folder? if not  and try to add it to it and execute , i hope it should work for you..

Comment: The slf4j jar is avilable in the library folder. Tried executing it many times. Still not working!

Comment: Try with slf4j-api-1.6.0.jar. It contains LoggerFactory.

Comment: I copied the maven dependency from the maven repo as:
-----------
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.25</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
--------
well it was the darn scope!  Just remove or comment out the scope line and try running your app again.

Answer (score 51):

[Add a SLF4J implementation (as you only have its API):](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 27):

You have to provide one of the various SLF4J implementation .jar files in the classpath, as well as the interface .jar file. This is documented.

Comment: The jar file, currently in the library is slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar, slf4j-jdk14-1.6.1.jar, slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar and slf4j-simple-1.6.1.jar. Can you please suggest me the correct implementation & interface jars that has to be included in the library.

Comment: Included slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar file in the library. Its not working. Is it enough to include the jar in library? Or else I have to set the classpath. If so can you please guide me how to set the classpath! Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can cause this error by having mismatched versions of e.g. `slf4j-api` and `slf4j-log4j12`.  Trying random versions of individual jars as suggested by @Gk. and other answers might solve it by coincidence, but the real answer is just to ensure that the jars being loaded are all of the same version.

Comment: @BalaRamachandran There is no 'correct implementation'. There is the one you want, and the others.

Comment: "This is documented." Ha okay, apparently not well enough!

Comment: @Andrew Well enough for me. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat I find your own comment utterly superfluous, and your tone offensive.

Answer (score 12):

[Download slf4j-1.7.5.zip](http://www.slf4j.org/download.html)

It holds different jar files.

Go to -> Integration folder after extracting zip and include following jar files

1. slf4j-api-2.0.99
2. slf4j-simple-1.6.99
3. junit-3.8.1

Answer (score 9):

Right click on project properties and follow below steps Project Properties" --> "Deployment Assembly", adding "Java Build Path Entries -> Maven Dependencies

Answer (score 8):

I tried other solutions and the exception didn't go away. So I decompiled the entire `jose4j 0.6.5 jar` with a Java Decomplier and look at its pom.xml.

I realised it has a specific dependency on **slf4j-api, version 1.7.21**:
[image]

So in my project's pom.xml, I added the exact same dependency, updated my Maven project so that it downloads this jar into my repository and the exception was gone.

However it may bring up another error caused by slf4j itself:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

To overcome this issue, I added the following into my project's pom.xml. So altogether you need to add the following to your pom.xml and my `jose4j` ran without anymore issues:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.21</version>
</dependency>   

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Remember to update your Maven project after amending your `pom.xml`.

(Right-click Project folder in Eclipse `->` Maven `->` Update Project..)

Answer (score 6):

I also had the similar problem. I had a maven project and was testing rabbitmq. Firstly it showed me the similar error then I added all the SLF4J dependencies in the maven project and then error changed to "Maven SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings". Here is the complete list of dependencies from pom.xlm

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
        <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
       <version>1.7.21</version>
       <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

It worked finally.

Comment: I've experienced this too, when migrating from V3.4 to V4.0 of RabbitMQ.  If you look at the RabbitMQ source, it uses a "Logger" instance that's intended to be SLF4J.  If you've used Log4J directly as the "Logger" then an exception is thrown.

See this in the POM for RabbitMQ:
   **<slf4j.version>1.7.21</slf4j.version>**

Answer (score 4):

I was facing a similar issue and below line fixed the issue for me.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Edit: I realized that I was using spring boot and the version of the dependency was getting pulled from spring-boot-starter-parent.

Comment: you need the version field, it's missing here

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderMills!

Answer (score 3):

Add the following jars to the class path or lib folder

1. [slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.2)
2. [slf4j-jdk14-1.7.2.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-jdk14/1.7.2)

Answer (score 2):

To be more specific if you are missing the class **com.vaadin.external.org.slf4j.LoggerFactory** add the below dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin.external.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

If you are missing any other **org.slf4j.LoggerFactory**, just go to [Maven central class name search](http://search.maven.org/#advancedsearch%7Cgav) and search for the exact class name to determine what exact dependency you are missing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use bellow dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

The perfect solution which works undoubtedly is to just add these packages to your app:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.2 
http://archive.apache.org/dist/logging/log4j/1.2.16/

after adding so you may encounter following WARNING which you can simply ignore!
 *SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.*

credits:
https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2018/02/fix-exception-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-slf4j-loggerfactory-java.html

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs because of referenced jars are not checked in our project's order and export tab.

Choose Project ->ALT+Enter->Java Build Path ->Order and Export->check necessary jar files into  your project.

Finally clean your project and run.It will run successfully.

Answer (score 1):

You need slf4j-api library. For most cases only slf4j-api and slf4j-jkd14 are only required:

[Here](https://hub.jazz.net/project/morenoli/hangmangame/overview#https://hub.jazz.net/gerrit/plugins/gerritfs/list/morenoli%252Fhangmangame/refs%252Fheads%252Fmaster/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib) you can download the version 1.7.2:

```
slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar
slf4j-jkd14-1.7.2jar
```

If you need an example to see how these are used, refers to this tutorial: 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-hangman-app/index.html

All the [code](https://hub.jazz.net/project/morenoli/hangmangame/overview?utm_source=developerWorks&utm_medium=article&utm_content=j-hangman-app&utm_campaign=dW%20CloudOE%20content) for the tutorial is available

Answer (score 1):

When we use the slf4j api jar, we need any of the logger implementations like log4j. On my system, we have the complete set and it works fine.

```
1. slf4j-api-1.5.6.jar
2. slf4j-log4j12-1.5.6.jar
3. **log4j-1.2.15.jar**
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is outlined on the slf4j web-site ([Failed to load class org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder))

For a very quick solution I suggest adding no-operation (NOP) logger implementation (slf4j-nop.jar)

For example, if using maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4j-nop-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue for zookeeper start up.

```
# sh /opt/zookeeper-3.4.13-1.hardtop.0.9.1/bin/zkServer.sh start-foreground
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /opt/zookeeper-3.4.13-1.hardtop.0.9.1/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.<clinit>(QuorumPeerMain.java:67)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 1 more
```

But the class is already there as part of other slf4j jars:

```
# grep LoggerFactory lib/*jar
Binary file lib/log4j-1.2-api-2.17.1.jar matches
Binary file lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.1.jar matches
Binary file lib/netty-all-4.1.30.Final.jar matches
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure your **MANIFEST.MF** contains the name of the referenced jar in my application was **slf4j-api-*. jar**.

Answer (score 0):

get the compatible version of this jar slf4j-jdk14 and add it as a dependency.
this solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need slf4j-api library and slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25 jar. Copy this jars in your project-> WEBINF-> lib folder and in tomcat server lib folder to execute successfully.

Answer (score 0):

When you copy dependency from maven repository there is:

```
<scope>test</scope>
```

Try to remove it from dependencies in pom.xml like this.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

This works for me. I hope it would be helpful for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me /properties/maven uncheck resolve dependencies from Workspace projects.

Answer (score 0):

First, check the dependency hierarchy than to exclude all slf4j jars from other dependencies and add separate slf4j as dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not maven project then make sure the **jar file is inside the project folder**. If it is a maven project then make sure **it's in the pom.xml**.

Answer (score 0):

After trying everything mentioned here, this maven dependency helped me:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

use maven it will download all the required jar files for you.

in this case you need the below jar files:

slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar

These jars will also depend on the cassandra version which you are running.
 There are dependencies with cassandra version , jar version and jdk version you use.

You can use : jdk1.6
with : cassandra 1.1.12
and the above jars.

Answer (score -1):

If you are facing java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

Add slf4j-log4j12 jar in the library folder of the project

Answer (score -3):

The LoggerFactory class is msising according to the error message:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

Apparently, the `slf4j.jar` file is not getting loaded for some reason.