# Maven run batch from command line, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, maven, command-line

I have a problem with maven and the execution of a java class call through the command line.

My application uses spring,hibernate and maven.

My little piece of pom.xml is this:

```
<profile>
<id>import</id>
<build>
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
   <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <executions>
    <execution>
     <goals>
      <goal>java</goal>
     </goals>
     <phase>test</phase>
      <configuration>
        <mainClass>com.mycompany.App</mainClass>
      </configuration>
     </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
 </plugins>
</build>
</profile>
```

I tried to run from eclipse and my application works, while on the command line like this:
mvn test -Pimport
I have some errors like:

```
"nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory"
```

Eg: dependency is so defined:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
<artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
<version>1.5.8</version>
<scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you may have the same issue as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12926912/61624).  You should have an implementation jar on your classpath, too.  For example

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8</version>
        </dependency>
```

Do you have anything else that mentions slf4j in your pom.xml?