# JasperReports: getting "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory" Exception

Tags: java, jasper-reports, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception

I have created a report (*JasperReports 5.5*) using the *JasperReports plugin* for *NetBeans 6.9.1* (*Java 1.6*). I can create a report and the report can be successfully viewed using the Preview tab of the *JasperReports Plugin*. But when I use *Java* code to access the  report it gives the following Error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:131)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:272)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.<clinit>(JRLoader.java:68)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRPropertiesUtil.loadProperties(JRPropertiesUtil.java:99)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.DefaultJasperReportsContext.initProperties(DefaultJasperReportsContext.java:94)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.DefaultJasperReportsContext.<init>(DefaultJasperReportsContext.java:71)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.DefaultJasperReportsContext.<clinit>(DefaultJasperReportsContext.java:59)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.getDefaultInstance(JasperCompileManager.java:84)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:459)
    at Interfaces.MainMenu.jMenuItem3ActionPerformed(MainMenu.java:854)
    at Interfaces.MainMenu.access$1300(MainMenu.java:50)
    at Interfaces.MainMenu$14.actionPerformed(MainMenu.java:494)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:357)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:809)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:850)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6288)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6053)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4651)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4577)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:643)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:602)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:600)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:616)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:614)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:613)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 51 more
```

When I add the mentioned JAR file it gives the same error with a different JAR and it goes on and on.

I have used the following code to access the report.

```
try {
        String report = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\WarrantReport.jrxml";
        JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(report);
        JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, null, c);
        JasperViewer.viewReport(jp);
    } catch (JRException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainMenu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

I have added the following 5 JAR files to my Project folder Libraries:
jasperreports 5.5 applet, fonts, functions, javaflow.

Please help me find the error.

Comment: You should consider using some dependecy managers like maven. Those really help solve no class def found exceptions becouse they automatically get all needed jars.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926899/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-slf4j-loggerfactory)

Comment: @AlexK.. can you please elaborate? your answer is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

A `NoClassDefFoundError` with `ClassNotFoundException` specifies that the particular class is missing during runtime. For the `LoggerFactory` to be available you should have any of [these jars](http://www.findjar.com/class/org/slf4j/LoggerFactory.html) in your classpath.

You can further [debug a NoClassDefFoundError here](http://javareferencegv.blogspot.com/2013/10/debugging-javalangnoclassdeffounderror.html)