# WebLogic Server Deployment

Tags: weblogic, weblogic11g

I am getting following error, when I deploy ear file in to web logic. I have added slf4 jar in to my war. 
java.lang.classNotFoundException:org.slf4.LoggFactory

I added jar file to lib folder in web logic too but still not able to solve.

Comment: I hope you understood my problem.

Comment: I am new to web logic.please help on this...

Comment: Could be typo in the question, but looking inside an slf4j-api jar file, the class is org.slf4j.Logg**er**Factory.  If it's just the question that is wrong, could you add some detail on exactly which jar file you are adding please?

Comment: I am adding slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar

Answer (score 0):

You may find some help on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926899/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-slf4j-loggerfactory) similar thread, it mentions adding a jar to the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes your application jars will conflict with the ones provided by WebLogic. I've seen this happen frequently with slf4j. Try adding the following to the weblogic.xml file:

```
<wls:container-descriptor>
    <wls:prefer-application-packages>
    <wls:package-name>org.slf4j</wls:package-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>
</wls:container-descriptor>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But Where Can I find weblogic.xml in weblogic server? Or Do I need to add in my applicatuion..?

Comment: Add in your project in the same directory as your web.xml.