# PWC1257: Error configuring application listener of class org.apache.tiles.web.startup.TilesListener

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tiles, loggerfactory

I integrated **tiles** with spring mvc web application successfully in **windows 7** OS. But when I tried same thing in **windows server 2008 R2** machine, I am getting the following error:

```
WebModule[/Vela-web-client]PWC1257: Error configuring application listener of class org.apache.tiles.web.startup.TilesListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:131)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:272)
    at org.apache.tiles.web.startup.TilesListener.<init>(TilesListener.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4576)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5312)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:989)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:704)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1627)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1232)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.WebModuleDeployEventListener.moduleDeployed(WebModuleDeployEventListener.java:182)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.WebModuleDeployEventListener.moduleDeployed(WebModuleDeployEventListener.java:278)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.event.AdminEventMulticaster.invokeModuleDeployEventListener(AdminEventMulticaster.java:1005)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.event.AdminEventMulticaster.handleModuleDeployEvent(AdminEventMulticaster.java:992)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.event.AdminEventMulticaster.processEvent(AdminEventMulticaster.java:470)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.event.AdminEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(AdminEventMulticaster.java:182)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.server.core.DeploymentNotificationHelper.multicastEvent(DeploymentNotificationHelper.java:308)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.DeploymentServiceUtils.multicastEvent(DeploymentServiceUtils.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.ServerDeploymentTarget.sendStartEvent(ServerDeploymentTarget.java:298)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.ApplicationStartPhase.runPhase(ApplicationStartPhase.java:132)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.DeploymentPhase.executePhase(DeploymentPhase.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.PEDeploymentService.executePhases(PEDeploymentService.java:966)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.PEDeploymentService.start(PEDeploymentService.java:609)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.PEDeploymentService.start(PEDeploymentService.java:653)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.mbeans.ApplicationsConfigMBean.start(ApplicationsConfigMBean.java:773)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.MBeanHelper.invokeOperationInBean(MBeanHelper.java:381)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.MBeanHelper.invokeOperationInBean(MBeanHelper.java:364)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.config.BaseConfigMBean.invoke(BaseConfigMBean.java:477)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:761)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.util.proxy.ProxyClass.invoke(ProxyClass.java:90)
    at $Proxy1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.server.core.jmx.SunoneInterceptor.invoke(SunoneInterceptor.java:304)
    at com.sun.enterprise.interceptor.DynamicInterceptor.invoke(DynamicInterceptor.java:174)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.jmx.remote.server.callers.InvokeCaller.call(InvokeCaller.java:69)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.jmx.remote.server.MBeanServerRequestHandler.handle(MBeanServerRequestHandler.java:155)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.jmx.remote.server.servlet.RemoteJmxConnectorServlet.processRequest(RemoteJmxConnectorServlet.java:122)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.jmx.remote.server.servlet.RemoteJmxConnectorServlet.doPost(RemoteJmxConnectorServlet.java:193)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.servletService(ApplicationFilterChain.java:427)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:315)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:287)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:94)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1096)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1096)
    at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:288)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(DefaultProcessorTask.java:647)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.doProcess(DefaultProcessorTask.java:579)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.process(DefaultProcessorTask.java:831)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.executeProcessorTask(DefaultReadTask.java:341)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:263)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:214)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:265)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.WorkerThreadImpl.run(WorkerThreadImpl.java:116)
PWC1258: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
```

I used the following necessary jars: (it should be sufficient enough since I run in Win7)

```
tiles-api-2.1.2
tiles-core-2.1.2
tiles-jsp-2.1.2
tiles-servlet-2.1.2
commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0
commons-digester-1.8
commons-logging-api-1.1.1
```

I also added extra jars (**slf4j-api-1.5.5 / slf4j-api-1.6.0 / slf4j-api-1.7.12 / slf4j-log4j12-1.5.5**) to solve the problem but also no success. I visited [the referred question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12926912/1271985) but no success.

My **web.xml** confiugration:

```
<context-param> 
    <param-name> 
        org.apache.tiles.definition.DefinitionsFactory.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG 
    </param-name> 
    <param-value> 
        /WEB-INF/myTilesConfigFile.xml 
    </param-value> 
</context-param> 
<listener> 
    <listener-class>org.apache.tiles.web.startup.TilesListener</listener-class> 
</listener>
```

Now, can someone please help me what am I missing? I already spent a full day searching in google for a possible solution but not getting the right one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926899/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-slf4j-loggerfactory)

Comment: @Shahzeb: The problem seems similar but my situation is different. In my win7 machine, it runs without any of the 4 jars mentioned in later but in windows server 2008, it don't after including these jars! Thanks for the referred question. I already visited it.

Comment: Nothing to do with windows has to be class path. In you IDE try to open the implementation . I bet there is no implementation .

Comment: @Shahzeb: Thanks for your comment. Please tell me which jars need to add. I already tried 4 jars (different version) independently. Thanks in advance

Comment: From that other question I posted , I would say add `slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar` bascially just an implementation.

Comment: @Shahzeb: I tried your specific version 1.6.6 but still same problem. Don't understand what's going on!