# new JedisPool is getting a NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, jedis

I'm going to create a Jedis pool, (in a really simple way)

but I got this error below:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JedisPoolConfig jedisPoolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
        jedisPoolConfig.setMaxTotal(10);
        new JedisPool(jedisPoolConfig, "localhost");
    }
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at redis.clients.jedis.HostAndPort.<clinit>(HostAndPort.java:12)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.<init>(JedisFactory.java:58)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.<init>(JedisFactory.java:50)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.<init>(JedisFactory.java:36)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.<init>(JedisPool.java:221)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.<init>(JedisPool.java:165)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.<init>(JedisPool.java:137)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.<init>(JedisPool.java:76)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.<init>(JedisPool.java:120)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.<init>(JedisPool.java:103)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.<init>(JedisPool.java:22)
    at JedisPoolUtils.main(JedisPoolUtils.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 12 more
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926899/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-slf4j-loggerfactory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jedis](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/redis.clients/jedis/2.10.1) has slf4j-api as a compile dependency, you need to add slf4j-api jar to your application

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.30